# How to add 2 Icon in Notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add an additional icon along with the app icon in notification.

This is what I am getting

[image: Actual Image]

And this is what I want
[image: Expected Image]